# How to deploy a Laravel project on cPanel/ Shared hosting leaving out "node_modules" folder

Tags: laravel, cpanel, node-modules, shared-hosting

Is there a "BETTER" way of deploying a Laravel project in cPanel without coping the "node_modules" folder, cause its really big and I assume there should be a way to leave out that folder. Im asking cause I have seen a lot of tutorials that include "node_modules" folder.

Comment: Do not know what  you mean by "BETTER" way, just delete the folder, it has no effect on your application. since the app is already compiled.

Comment: "node_modules" for js project, you're using Laravel so I think it for your react/vuejs(front-end), and they do have distribution folder can run without "node_modules". But first, check "node_modules" belong to what.

Comment: @AbdelillahAissani I mean better coz I have seen tutorials where people include node modules in the cPanel, so yes Im asking coz I have given it a great deal of research. Thank you for your input.

Answer (score 1):

You can try first on local server without node_modules your application working fine or not then you can deploy without node_module

Comment: Thank you for your input. I will try that.